# Using Boost Windows Installer - do I still need to make the non header only libraries?

Tags: boost, hyperlink

I'm using the Boost Windows installer provided by boostpro.com and already have all the compiled binaries present in my boost_1.44/lib folder. However, when I'm trying to use the boost filesystem library, I'm getting a build error saying that

LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_system-vc90-mt-gd-1_44.lib'

I'm using Visual Studio 9, and I don't have a file called 'libboost_system-vc90-mt-gd-1_44.lib'. Any ideas on what I should do next?

Answer (score 1):

You either need to compile the variant of Boost with "threading=multi runtime-debugging=on variant=debug" as that's not a variant that normally comes with the BoostPro installer (AFAIK); or switch your project to use a different variant. Most likely you need to turn off the "runtime-debugging=on" in VC, which translates to turning off the debug STD. See the [Getting Started](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#library-naming) for what the name of the library it's asking for means.